# Stripe API PHP - Retrieve balance of Managed Account

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I've been going through the documentation and cannot seem to find anyway to directly request balance data for a managed account.

using:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("MY_API_KEY");
\Stripe\Balance::retrieve("MANAGED_ACCOUNT_ID");
```

returns error: 
`Invalid API Key provided: "MANAGED_ACCOUNT_ID"`

Removing the managed account id I do get all balance info for my platform account but as yet cannot get any balance info for any managed accounts.
Is this even possible? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: `\Stripe\Balance::retrieve()` does not expect an argument. What are you trying to get? A customer balance? All customers balances? You can retrieve individual customer balances by passing a transaction id to `\Stripe\BalanceTransaction::retrieve("txn_id");`

Comment: Does `\Stripe\Balance::retrieve(array("stripe_account" =>"acct_xxxyyyzzz"));` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the `stripe_account` parameter, like this:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxyyyyzzzzz");
echo \Stripe\Balance::retrieve(array("stripe_account" => "acct_16Y3BkIjdPh5WEvB"));
?>
```

Comment: The retrieve method does not expect arguments: https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#retrieve_balance

Comment: Yes! That did exactly what I wanted it to. Thanks very much duck.